# In Python Pandas, not able to use np.where to perform divide calculation using the 'if True' argument. Any alternatives?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe depicting a stock's price. Columns depicting different prices (open, low, high, close) and rows depicting time.

[image]

[CSV of data sample here:](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aj99irJinMf5g41UrL6R8v7pZRghqA?e=d64mpY)

I'm trying to perform a if else function to perform different calculation per row, and output the result to a new column "cond14". Results should be True / False.

In plain english,

1. check first that the current row's close price is not = to open price, AND the previous' row close price is not = to open price.
2. if above is true, check that the distance btw current row's close & open price is less than 20 times the distance btw the previous row's close & open price.
3. if (1) is not true, check if the open / low / high close prices are the same for the previous row.
4. if (3) is True, output "False" into new column "cond14". If (3) is False, output "True" into new column "cond14"

So with this, I implemented the following that only checks the last two rows of a dataframe. Seems to work.

```
if abs(candles.close[-1]-candles.open[-1]) > 0.01 and abs(candles.close[-2]-candles.open[-2]) > 0.01: #210605: to prevent oversized candles see DQ 0601
        cond14 = (abs(candles.close[-1]-candles.open[-1])/abs(candles.close[-2]-candles.open[-2])) < 20
    elif candles.close[-2] == candles.open[-2] == candles.high[-2] == candles.low[-2]:
        cond14 = False
    else:
        cond14 = True
```

With this, I need to "backtest" this against all the rows in the dataframe.

I'm still learning python and I read around that numpy functions are the best to use with dataframes.

```
    df.loc[:, ('Mcond14')] = np.where((df.close != df.open) & (df.close.shift(1) != df.open.shift(1)), (abs(df.close-df.open)/abs(df.close.shift(1)-df.open.shift(1))) < 20,
        (np.where(df.close.shift(1) == df.open.shift(1) == df.high.shift(1) == df.low.shift(1)), False, True))
```

I tried the above code, but it gave me the following error:

```
  File "tMIC.py", line 43, in check_micro
    (np.where(df.close.shift(1) == df.open.shift(1) == df.high.shift(1) == df.low.shift(1)), False, True))
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1326, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I [read the numpy docs for .where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), it seems like the outcome if True / False can only be values, and cannot be further calculations?

Or is there something else I'm not understanding correctly?

Comment: The logic of IF/ELSE is not complete. What about the result of the check in step 2? You don't declare any actions for TRUE/FALSE of this step

Comment: Oh, if step 2 depicts what happens if it's True, which is to do that distance check is less than 20 times. If step 2 is False, proceed to run step 3.

Comment: @IoaTzimas updated the question post to clarify this.

Comment: Yeah sorry, please ignore my comment, as this is not an issue

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this part of the code:

```
np.where(df.close.shift(1) == df.open.shift(1) == df.high.shift(1) == df.low.shift(1))
```

Here is some working solution:

```
df.loc[:, ('Mcond14')] = np.where((df.close != df.open) & (df.close.shift(1) != df.open.shift(1)), abs(df.close-df.open)/abs(df.close.shift(1)-df.open.shift(1)) < 20, np.where((df.close.shift(1) == df.open.shift(1)) & (df.close.shift(1) == df.high.shift(1)) & (df.close.shift(1) == df.low.shift(1)), False, True))
```